# Сумма элементов диагонали

Tags: массивы, pascal

Не могу до конца дописать программу про массив, помогите.

Задание.

> В массиве целых положительных и отрицательных чисел А[4,4], полученном случайным образом, вычислить сумму элементов побочной диагонали и третьего столбца. Если сумма элементов побочной диагонали больше суммы элементов третьего столбца, то выбрать из массива все числа меньше 25, и записать их в одномерный массив, который затем рассортировать в порядке возрастания. В противном случае подсчитать количество четных чисел в массиве А и записать его на место третьего элемента первой строки.

```
Program massiv 40;_
Var_
i, j, Sg, B : integer;_
a: array[1..4, 1..4] of integer;_
begin_
clrscr; {очистка экрана}_
randomize; {инициализация генератора случайных чисел}_
writeln ('massiv A');_
far i: 1 to 4 do_
begin {получение случайного массива и вывод его на экран}_
A[i,j]:= random (200)-100;_
write (A[i,j]:4);_
end; {for j}_
writeln;_
end; {for i}_
Sg:= 0;_
Sp:= 0;_
for i:= 1 to 4 do_
begin_    (А дальше я не знаю, как правильно, начало вроде правильное, помогите)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю паскаля но вот пример:

---

Сначала подсчитаем сумму в 3м столбце

```
for i:=0 to 3 do // цикл перебора i от 0 до 3 начинается(т.к. у нас 4 строки, а от 0 до 4                     это уже 5 значений)
begin
Sum = Sum + A[i, 3]
end;
```

---

Поиск суммы в побочной диагонали: (Сам принцип)

Матрица 4х4

```
a11 a12 a13 a14

a21 a22 a23 a24

a31 a32 a33 a34

a41 a42 a43 a44
```

Итак нам нужна диагональ **a14-a41**, поэтому делаем цикл

```
for i от 4 до 1 и j от 1 до 4

Далее Sum2 = Sum2 + а[i,j]
```

---

И теперь

`if Sum<Sum2` то выполнить

```
 for i от 1 до 4 и j от 1 до 4 и k от 1 до 16
   if A[i,j]<25 than B[k]=A[i,j]
```

**Рассортируешь его**=)

```
else

for i от 1 до 4 и j от 1 до 4
  //Сдесь тебе надо искать "Остаток от деления"
    if A[i,j] mod 2 == 0 than Sum = Sum +A[i,j] // Получили число всех четных
    end;
```

На третье место первой строки `A[1,3] = Sum;`

Comment: диагональ a14-a41 - `for i от 1 до 4 -> Sum2 = Sum2 + а[5-i,i]`